# What is a buffer on java?

Tags: java, buffer

I have a homework to do on Java and is asks me to create a buffer method and the constructor should make an empty buffer structure.

There is no details about what that buffer is. It also wants to insert chars inside the buffer, delete the char that buffer shows, go buffer X positions left or right and tell the number of buffers chars. All these with different methods.

The problem is WHAT IS THAT BUFFER??? Is this something specific?

Comment: Hover the mouse over the buffer tag you added in your question, then start reading. For more info about it, select the info link in the popup.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with...[Buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html), specifically [CharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html)? C'mon OP, you only had to type "java buffer" into Google instead of the tags on StackOverflow.

Comment: OK. So let's say buffer is just a FIFO STRING and each buffer item shows a value and the positions of the old value.What are we doing on methods. void left(int k "how many positions it moves") and void right(int k "How many positions it moves")

Comment: Why not ask your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).  There are many other possible solutions but StringBuilder is the most widely used buffer for chars these days.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidler();
```

> It also wants to insert chars inside the buffer,

```
sb.append('!');
sb.append("Hello");
sb.insert(5, "bye");
```

> delete the char that buffer shows,

```
sb.delete(3, 6);
```

> go buffer X positions left or right and tell the number of buffers chars.

```
 sb.charAt(5); // character at 5
 int len = sb.length(); // number of characters.
```